# Homework - NFA and its regular expression.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

So for **(a)** I got this:

[image]

I THINK that is right, I'm not too sure. But I am also having a lot of trouble doing **(b)**. Any pointers to get me started would be appreciated.

Comment: Your machine won't accept $cca$ which is in the language.

Comment: @copper.hat Okay now I'm more confused. So it has to be ucva and cca is accepted. Shouldnt that mean c is in u? But u is {a, b}*?

Comment: No, $\epsilon \in \{a,b\}^*$.

Comment: It must be possible to end up in the accepting state with input $cca$. However, the above machine will be left in state $q_1$.

Comment: @copper.hat i updated my nfa. is that looking better?

Comment: The only legal exit from $q_3$ is an $a$. You should remove the $b,c$ loop $q_3 \to q_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four parts, $u,c,v,a$. $u \in \{a,b\}^*$, so write $(a|b)^*$ for that, $c$ is easy, $v$ has length one, and is any character, so is $(a|b|c)$, and $a$ is easy. Combining gives $(a|b)^* c(a|b|c)a$.

Comment: What if the input language is empty? Don't I have to put a condition so that the NFA doesn't recognise the language if it's empty?

Comment: The regular expression is equivalent to the language above. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the 'input language is empty'?

Comment: I mean, will it accept an empty string, or SHOULD it accept an empty string?

Comment: No, $\epsilon \notin L$. It can't be because any string in $L$ must have a $c$ (and another letter followed by $a$).